# Английский текст от некоторых пользователей

Tags: обсуждение, тематика

Уже не первый раз я встречаю индивидов, которые пишут свои ответы на английском языке. Что предлагается делать с подобными? Этот сайт для русскоязычных пользователей и, я считаю, никакой другой язык использовать на данном сайте неуместно.

Некоторые оправдывают подобное поведение, мол, любой уважающий себя программист должен знать английский язык. Это всё хорошо и замечательно, только вот их забыли спросить, кто кому чего должен. Так вот, что делать-то с упёртыми "англичанами"?

Comment: Вежливо предупреждать, при доброй воле переводить самому ручную, если не влом. При злостном игнорировании формата ставить «тревоги» и ждать живительного бана.

Comment: Ok guys. Let's all together speak English in this thread. I'll start. London is the capital of Great Britain.

Comment: I'm Muzzy! Big Muzzy! I like clocks!

Comment: @VladD, Where is Wally? Let's find him!

Comment: Игнорировать. Можно после комментария, что тут говорят по русски.

Comment: snooky wants smush-smush

Comment: Humpty-Dumpty
Sat on a wall,
Humpty-Dumpty
Had a great fall;
All the King's horses
And all the King's man
Couldn't put Humpty
Together again.

Comment: I'm so sorry that I studied German language in the school. Or it was French... Anyway, I don't know very much English.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Следует ли переводить вопросы, которые задали на других языках?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1051/181472)

Comment: Не хотите английский? [Получайте украинский](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/142030)!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Содержимое на русском SO должно быть на русском.

Один из принципов большого SO: assume good faith, поэтому сперва достаточно оставить комментарий-напоминание о языке и/или если ответ небольшой, то просто перевести его на русский. Автор ответа мог просто по ошибке не тот язык использовать.

Если автор сознательно английский использует, и отказывается добавить перевод, то  минусовать ответ и добавить свой ответ с переводом (по желанию).

Если участник постоянно английский использует, то можно привлечь внимание модератора (за вандализм).

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста как мне правильно привлечь внимание модераторов к пользователю, который регулярно задает не корректные вопросы?

Comment: @IgorSergeevich: нажмите кнопку «тревога» под соответствующим вопросом: если ситуация не подпадает под перечисленные стандартные причины, то выберите «требуется вмешательство модератора» и *подробно* изложите, чем вопрос "некорректен" по вашему мнению (если вы не уверены в корректности, то не упоминая явно пользователя (можно ссылку на вопрос привести) опишите поведение, которое вызывает сомнение на Мете (не фокусируйтесь на человеке, спрашивайте про приемлемость/полезность/вред для сайта конкретного поведения вместо этого -- обсуждайте конкретное поведение, а не человека).

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ

Answer (score 12):

Ответ VladD:

---

Вежливо предупреждать, при доброй воле переводить самому вручную, если не влом. При злостном игнорировании формата ставить «тревоги» и ждать живительного бана.

Answer (score 12):

Здесь русский SO и вопросы и ответы на нем должны быть на русском. Такова его цель - собрание базы знаний по программированию на русском языке. Для английских ответов есть английский SO.

Предупреждать, если не понимают - поднимать флажки тревоги.

*Есть подозрение, что это может быть просто копипастой, когда отвечающему самому влом переводить ответ на русский.*