# Дублирование ответа на RU SO

Tags: обсуждение

У меня есть вопрос на английской версии SO, на который нет ответа.

Я хочу, чтобы данный вопрос был виден также и на русской версии SO.

Я должен просто задать новый вопрос на RU_SO, или есть какой-то способ создать копию вопроса, но на другом языке? Как лучше поступать в таких случаях?

Будет ли считаться вопрос заданный на другом языке дубликатом?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Нет, способа создать копию на другом языке нет (а немного жаль). Просто напишите отдельный вопрос здесь. Желательно добавив ссылку на оригинальный вопрос - чтобы можно было почитать комментарии и ответы.

Причем лучше писать сразу на русском, а не копипаст с английской версии. Практика показывает - вопросы заданные на английском у нас здесь многие очень недолюбливают, и начинают ставить минусы и гневно комментировать, даже если вопрос довольно толковый. Хоть и да, обычно буквально через пару минут кто-нибудь из сообщества переводит вопрос на русский.

Comment: Хотел еще тогда уточнить как поступать если на одном из сайтов появился ответ на вопрос, мне стоит закрыть вопрос на другом сайте или самому скопировать ответ в другой сайт ? Или есть какой то другой вариант? ( с точки зрения полезности для других пользователей хорошо бы было иметь ответ на обоих языках)

Comment: @Batanichek перевод требует усилий, поэтому если речь о переводе ответа в сообщество на другом языке, вперёд! Это полезный вклад в сообщество. Но копировать ответ (да и вопрос) без изменений не стоит -- это уже кросс-постинг, [который в сети SE не одобряется](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Comment: @Batanichek , думаю лучше на другом сайте оставить вопрос открытым - возможно со временем появится даже более интересный ответ. Ну и если есть время/желание - можете самостоятельно ответить на свой вопрос, переведя лучший ответ с другого языка(используемая здесь лицензия [cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) вполне позволяет делать так, но с указанием автора и с ссылкой на оригинальный вопрос(а это уже [требование SO](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/))).

Comment: *вопросы заданные на английском у нас здесь многие очень недолюбливают* — интересный у вас взгляд на ru.so. вообще-то сайт и предназначен для общения на русском. и если автор вопроса не хочет (или ему лень) переводить вопрос, то это либо должен сделать кто-то другой за него, либо вопрос должен быть закрыт (возможно, с перенесением его на en.so, что в данном конкретном случае бессмысленно).

Comment: Вопросы на английском как правило не минусуют, а закрывают и/или отмечают тревогой для модератора. Потом если кто-либо переводит, то переоткрывают, а если нет — то модератор договаривается и переносит на другой сайт. Сам переносил два или три вопроса — гневных комментариев не было.

Answer (score 12):

Если мне долго не отвечают на русском (либо я хочу получить ответ как можно скорее), то делаю так: задаю вопросы на обоих языках, в конце каждого PS со ссылкой на вопрос на другом языке. Когда дают хороший ответ, размещаю его на втором сайте.

---

Примеры:

[Многократно запрашивается поиск по DOM'у одних и тех же элементов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/476703/178988)
[Multiple searching of the same elements in DOM](//stackoverflow.com/q/34402369/4928642)

[Имитация множественного наследования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/473837/178988)
[Imitate multiple inheritance](//stackoverflow.com/q/34232656/4928642)

[Перегрузка с первым необязательным параметром](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/467538/178988)
[Overload with first optional parameter](//stackoverflow.com/q/33813922/4928642)

[Ручной контроль над содержимым компонента React.js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/464085/178988)
[Getting full control over content of React.js component](//stackoverflow.com/q/33632643/4928642)

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/462316/178988
[How to animate path shape without using SMIL?](//stackoverflow.com/q/33420323/4928642)

[Как прокинуть браузерное событие через кастомное?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/457207/178988)
[How to pass browser event through the custom one?](//stackoverflow.com/q/33045147/4928642)

[Обрезать с добавлением многоточия многострочный форматированный текст по размеру скрытого контейнера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/445167/178988)
[How to crop with ellipsis formatted multiline text inside of ahidden block?](//stackoverflow.com/q/32215283/4928642)

[Запуск глобальных модулей nodejs из кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/434183/178988)
[How to start a globally installed module as an an application frome the code?](//stackoverflow.com/q/31478431/4928642)

Comment: Так же делаю. Если сам нашёл ответ — то в некоторых случаях перевожу вопрос и ответ целиком и публикую на втором сайте.

Answer (score 7):

> Будет ли считаться вопрос заданный на другом языке дубликатом?

Тематика SO на русском *практически* является объединением тематики (некоторых) уже существующих SE сайтов, поэтому существование похожего вопроса на другом языке само по себе не является причиной, чтобы закрыть/удалить вопрос с сайта.

***Если вопрос является [хорошим вопросом для SO на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), то естественно его можно на ru.SO задать.***

> Я должен просто задать новый вопрос на RU_SO или есть какой то способ создать копию вопроса , но на другом языке? Как лучше поступать в таких случаях?

Не имеет значения, что *похожий* вопрос можно также задать на каком-то другом SE сайте (Stack Overflow, Server Fault, etc), но [*нельзя просто копировать один и тот же вопрос как есть (copy-paste)*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu#comment181805_75012) — необходимо **адаптировать вопрос для каждого сообщества отдельно**. В частности, [вопросы на английском недопустимы на SO на русском](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342/23044).

Также вопрос, который является *буквальным переводом*, вероятно будет не самым лучшим вопросом (поэтому кнопка: *«создать копию на другом языке»* будет скорее вредна):

- терминология, порождаемая машинным переводом, как правило неудовлетворительна ([достаточно посмотреть как сам сайт переводился](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1032/23044)) — вопрос должен использовать словарь, понимаемый автором вопроса (человеком), <sub>который даже может отражать пробелы в знаниях/заблуждения автора (это может помочь найти вопрос будущим посетителям из поисковиков с похожими заблуждениями)</sub>
- поправить ссылки на внешние ресурсы (ссылки на другие вопросы, книги, руководства  на русском), чтобы вопрос был как можно более самодостаточным для выбранного сообщества
- следовать практике использования меток, принятой в данном сайте, которая может отличаться (читайте описания соответствующих меток)

Практика модерирования и разрешённые темы могут быть слегка различны, — это может быть *одной из* причин, что вопрос может остаться открытым на одном сайте и быть закрытым на другом.

Если вы задали похожие вопросы на разных сайтах, то полезно ссылки добавить друг на друга (как и ссылки на другие похожие вопросы — вне зависимости от того кто автор вопроса).