# Что делать с ответами на других языках?

Tags: обсуждение, ответы, удаление-ответов

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/176469
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/684674/178988

У ответов нет закрытия, есть только удаление.
И если его удалить, то кто будет восстанавливать в случае перевода?

Или просто не трогать (жать <kbd>Пропустить</kbd>), в расчёте, что кто-то переведёт из очереди?

Comment: удалить или переводить :-) не хочешь удалять - переводи, не хочешь переводить - удаляй :)

Comment: @Grundy, так я просто пропустил))

Comment: Сжечь тебя теперь!

Comment: @Grundy, я ж не переводчик))

Comment: @alexolut, не хм-м, а сжечь!

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Английский текст от некоторых пользователей](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342/23044)

Answer (score 13):

### Удалять или переводить

1. не хочешь удалять - переводи
2. не хочешь переводить - удаляй

Comment: Пропускать совсем нельзя, дяденька? :)

Comment: @alexolut, конечно :-) ответ не на-русском - плохой ответ, так как он уже в очереди - нужно определить что с ним делать.

Comment: Разумно. Пропускают пусть те, кто этот вопрос не читал :)