# Участники, которые принципально пишут только на украинском

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, закрытие-вопросов, перевод-содержимого

> Updated. [Предложенный как дубликат вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342) не подходит к текущей ситуации. В случае английского языка мы имеем дело с языком, для которого есть более подходящий сайт, куда можно перенести вопрос и ответ. В текущей ситуации рассматривается язык, для которого такого подсайта нет.

На Stackoverflow на русском есть ряд участников, которые пишут вопросы и ответы на украинском языке.

Некоторые из них говорят, что не знают русского языка, другие видимо делают это принципиально. Прям кремень как принципиальные — и все комментарии под ответами не переубеждают.

Я не уверен, что всем присутствующим на сайте понятны посты написанные на украинском — вроде бы и языки достаточно родственные, но так просто прочитать не получится. Да и у нас тут судя по sitename вроде бы пока ещё So на русском а не на украинском/белорусском/и так далее.

Вопрос несколько раз за последний год подымался в чате, однако рискнуть вынести на открытое обсуждение так никто и не собрался. Давайте всё же попробуем без излишней политизированности и эмоций разобраться в вопросе и по возможности, попробовать выработать какую-то единую позицию. При этом я бы предпочёл, чтобы отвечающие и комментирующие постарались не приводить конкретные никнеймы участников: мы не их лично обсуждаем, а вопрос в целом.

Насколько я понимаю, вопрос о создании "Stack overflow на украинском" — это вещь на текущий момент невозможная: нет ни желания управляющей компании SE заняться этим вопросом, ни критической массы участников.

На текущий момент вопросы на украинском языке можно закрыть с формулировкой:

> Вопрос закрыт, так как на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято
>   задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на
>   русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском. 3

Но ещё острее проблема с ответами. Они как правило верные, просто помимо кода содержат пояснения на украинском языке. Формальных оснований для закрытия нет.

На текущий момент я вижу что сложился какой-то негласный консенсус: мы все делаем вид, что этих вопросов "кагбы нет" и не педалируем вопрос на уровень модераторов, чтобы те приструнили, забанили и т.п.

Стоит ли нам и дальше делать вид, что такого явления не существует? Или попробуем обсудить тему и наметить возможные варианты разрешения ситуации?

Updated. [Предложенный как дубликат вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342) не подходит к текущей ситуации. В случае английского языка мы имеем дело с языком, для которого есть более подходящий сайт, куда можно перенести вопрос и ответ. В текущей ситуации рассматривается язык, для которого такого подсайта нет.

Кроме того, если мы можем предложить сходное решение ("закрыть вопрос на украинском" и "перевести на русский", отбросив решение "перенести на английский"), то с ответами у нас нет никаких вариантов решения - ни в той теме, ни в этой. Ответы нельзя закрывать, переносить тем более.

Вопросу менее недели, я подозреваю, что ещё не весь спектр мнений был получен и не вижу смысла ограничивать высказывание мнений, чтобы за них также могли проголосовать.

Comment: _Формальных оснований для закрытия нет._ - ответы как ни странно нельзя закрыть :-)

Comment: Как человек с Украины :), должен заметить, что *"Некоторые из них говорят, что не знают русского языка"* - честно говоря, поверить в это не могу. Да, уже выросло поколение, которое не умеет грамотно писать по-русски (обычно при этом и по-украински тоже...), но чтоб совсем не знать... Лично я таких в обычной жизни никогда не встречал. Да и тогда как человек смог продраться через русскоязычный интерфейс? :) Словом, мое личное мнение - это просто дурная заполитизированность...

Comment: Думаю что даже правильные нужно просто закрывать, я думаю если на английском SO написать правильный ответ на русском или хинди, то тоже удалят, и будут правы.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Английский текст от некоторых пользователей](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342/23044)

Comment: можете дюжину примеров вопросов/ответов подобных найти? Могу представить что только единичные случаи возможны когда переводить отказываются (сам не встречал).

Comment: @jfs нужно поиском по словам популярным. Пример, [для затравки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0).

Comment: @alexolut есть ли там примеры, что отказывается принципиально переводить? (из нескольких вопросов за этот год)

Comment: @jfs примеры надо у AK просить. Я свою позицию высказал в ответе, что сообщений таких минимум.

Comment: @alexolut у меня был по крайней мере один случай когда я половину ответа на другом языке написал и не заметил этого.

Comment: @alexolut, по запросу "ласка", кстати, там только текст сообщения в коде на украинском, сами вопросы при этом на русском. ИМХО, сообщения в коде хоть на хинди могут быть, если сам вопрос при этом понятен без этих сообщений. *Внутреннего граммар-наци по привычке коробит от "будь-ласка" через дефис, хотя украинский учил очень давно, и то до 8 класса*

Comment: @insolor потому и "для затравки". Про сообщения в коде я также указал в своём ответе.

Comment: Имхо, идеальный ответ уже дан https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343/221228 Точно такие же механизмы можно применять к любому языку

Comment: @AntonShchyrov собственно, можно закрывать дубликатом, кмк.

Comment: @Arhad *"В случае английского языка мы имеем дело с языком, для которого есть более подходящий сайт, куда можно перенести вопрос и ответ."* Перенос [**крайне не рекомендуется**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4051/176217) в таких ситуациях.

Comment: Имхо если нет ресурса на твоем языке - переводи вопрос на английский и иди на основной ресурс

Comment: Это банальное неуважение ко всему сообществу. Хорошо, допустим такие личности очень сильно обижены на Россию и не могут себе позволить писать на русском языке. Но помимо них есть немало стран, жители которых успешно владеют как языком страны проживания, так и русским языком. Они приходят на русскоязычный ресурс за информацией, а не за политикой и обидами. На этом ресурсе казахи не пишут на казахском; латыши не пишут на латышском, поляки не пишут на польском. Только украинцы требуют, чтобы все вдруг выучили украинский. Однозначно минусовать и помечать как низкое качество.

Answer (score 28):

Имхо, проблема раздута. Вспоминаются только редкие случаи задания вопросов новыми участниками на украинском языке. Может быть, конечно, я просто по меткам не пересекаюсь с такими сообщениями, но тем не менее. Хотя ещё бывают ситуации, где язык вопроса русский, но текст в функциях вывода украинский. Это в принципе даже не проблема. Хотя я в таких случаях вообще предпочёл бы английский.

Но если описанная проблема действительно имеет место быть (или кто-то сталкивается чаще с такими ситуациями, чем я), то решение здесь должно быть ровно такое же как и для любого другого языка, отличного от русского. Вопрос закрываем с формулировкой, требующей перевода. Ответ (адекватный) - переводим, если кому не лень, после уведомления автора о недопустимости таких публикаций в дальнейшем. Если отвечающий смог понять вопрос, написанный на русском, то логично предположить, что и ответить сможет на русском, пусть и на ломанном, но всё же. И, кстати, править ломанный русский всё равно проще (большее количество участников сможет это сделать), нежели переводить с грамматически корректного украинского.

Comment: Кроме непересечения по меткам (а я сомневаюсь, что есть корреляция по меткам - по идее везде должно быть равномерно) возможно, что часть вопросов правится энтузиастами и возможно вы в очередях проверок не активно участвуете. Но я согласен, что массовости проблемы нет. И пока удавалось обойтись без крупных скандалов, конфликтов и войн правок. Хотелось бы и дальше чтобы было так - а для этого неплохо бы проблему а) вербализовать б) сделать это заранее, пока она не в острой фазе.

Comment: Перевод с украинского с помощью машинного перевода можно делать без проблем имхо (это возражение насчёт преимуществ ломаного русского).

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov машинный перевод можно делать с любого языка гугла :) Но такой машинный перевод надо ещё и отшлифовать потом, имхо, слишком много ненужной возни. Если отвечающий собирается на регулярной основе наполнять ruSO, ему следует использовать принятый здесь язык коммуникации. Ненароком представил ситуацию, что [все баги](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A339911+%5Bbug%5D+is%3Aq), которые я постил на MSE, были бы написаны на русском номинально :) Наверное, меня бы там забанили быстренько на хороший срок.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov только сначала надо найти хороший машинный переводчик. Потому что тот же гугл с украинского на русский переводит через промежуточный английский.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Меня яндекс устаивал всегда.

Comment: Я одно время с украинцами в контакте общался из интереса на украинском через гуглопереводчик. Действительно переводит хреново, приходится перефразировать подыскивая более или менее безопасные конструкции, в переводе которых уверен. Друзья кстати были в курсе что я украинский не знаю, но замечанию ни разу не делали. Хотя это из вежливости скорее всего.

Answer (score 27):

Много раз видел вопросы на украинском. В более чем половине случаев их автор весьма агрессивно писал в комментариях, что он украинец и будет писать на родном языке, невзирая на какие-то там правила. Такие вопросы надо закрывать не только потому, что они нарушают языковое ограничение, но и ввиду политической ангажированности.

А вот ответов на украинском языке я ни разу не видел. Но если мне таковые попадутся, да ещё и с плюсовым рейтингом, то даже не знаю, как потом удержаться от написания ответов на монгольском.

Comment: И тем не менее ответы на украинском есть. Под ними как правило два коммента - один с пятью плюсами "переведите на русский" (то есть ещё штук пять проверяющих skip'нули проверку, но согласились, что ответ стоит перевести) и опционально бывает как раз от автора ответа что он не планирует переводить. Несколько раз я видел как добрые люди переводили на русский.

Answer (score 18):

А мы тут чем-то отличаемся в этом плане от остальных сайтов сети? Про вопросы на английском у нас уже есть тред, тоже самое касается и украинского.

По поводу ответов: [How do I deal with non-English content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/1991579)

> - Answers written in non-English should be flagged as *very low quality*, although *not an answer* will generally be honoured too.
>
> **Please do not translate posts for the OP.** They need to be able to respond to feedback, and if they cannot themselves translate the post
> we cannot be certain that they can understand any feedback provided
> (by comments, answers, or Help Center content).

Так что:

1. Для вопросов у нас есть причина закрытия.
2. Для ответов на en SO есть тревога "**very low quality**". Нам такую же надо.

**P.S.** я не увидел списка с примерами таких вопросов/ответов. Имхо, проблема раздута из ничего.

Comment: После многократных закрытий вопросов и банов на мете за попытку протащить конкретику никнеймов - я не особо горю желанием вытаскивать конкретные посты в паблик, так как они будут от двух-трёх участников. Тем более, что их надо сейчас искать - и это не самая простая задача, так как нет поиска участников по городам и нельзя искать в комментариях фразы типа "переведите на русский". Но я попробую со временем поискать информацию и показать хотя бы вне so. Возможно, если кому-то попадётся на глаза - добавит в эту тему комментарием.

Comment: Предложение по поводу тревоги на ответе мне очень нравится, двумя руками за.

Comment: @AK [поиск по комментариям](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6651/176217), и по городам, вроде бы тоже искал кто-то не так давно.