# Требуется добавить информацию о тематике StackOverflow в выдаче поисковиков

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено

Есть у нас некоторая тенденция возникновения мусорных вопросов, не относящихся к тематике ресурса (примеры: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/911932/218063), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/838907/218063), [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/827342/218063) и т. д.). Как одна из причин, этому может служить то, что на запрос в поисковике `задать вопрос` (без каких-либо уточнений) SO есть в выдаче (в первой пятерке [в гугле](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81) и в первой десятке [в яндексе](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81)):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Безусловно это хорошо и правильно, но, как видно на скринах, в поисковой выдаче никак не обозначена тематика ресурса (вопросы по программированию и системному администрированию), только абсолютно лишнее для поисковой выдачи "мы предпочитаем вопросы, на которые можно дать конкретные ответы ...", отжирающее 2 ценных предложения, которые стоило бы использовать с большей пользой.

Более того, если в поиске набрать `задать вопрос по программированию`, то в выдаче будет ссылка на SO (первая и [у гугла](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81+%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E) и [у яндекса](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E), что радует), но ссылка эта ведет на страницу тура:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что, мне кажется, тоже не совсем правильным (ну какой новичок начнет сразу читать простыню текста и искать там внизу кнопку чтобы задать вопрос?).

Судя по всему, на странице поисковой выдачи отображается текст, находящийся в блоке справа, на [странице создания нового вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), и нам стоит внести в него корректировки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это позволит отсеять часть мусорных вопросов и, скорее всего, привлечь часть целевой аудитории.

Предлагаю обсудить этот вопрос в этом топике.

Comment: Интересно, на каком основании была выбрана метка [tag:многопоточность] на одном из вопросов :)

Comment: Подскажите, есть ли у вас предложения по новой фразе?

Comment: сколько таких примеров за год по порядку величины? Если всего в день ~100 вопросов, то сколько из десятков тысяч вопросов, выбирают очевидно постороннюю тему?

Comment: @jfs, если это хоть как-то можно посчитать, то как узнать сколько потенциальных спрашивающих ушло не разобравшись как тут задать вопрос, потому что из поисковика им была предложена страница тура, а не страница где можно написать вопрос? Мы можем только изменить ситуацию и посмотреть что это даст в будущем, благо, для этого нужно всего-то исправить или добавить пару предложений на одной странице, это не составит большого труда (надеюсь), надо просто сочинить эти предложения...

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, написал ответ, надеюсь, это привлечет внимание остальных участников или натолкнет кого-нибудь на интересную идею :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP по логам легко посмотреть куда люди после тура идут. Если люди не могут задать вопрос после тура, то либо тур ужасный либо нужны ли нам такие люди?

Comment: Знал я одного сеошника, он раскручивал автосалоны под фразу "продажа авто", пытался ему доказать что живые люди никогда так не пишут, все пишут "купить авто". Переубедить я его так и не смог, наверно косноязычный слишком.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Надо определённо что-то делать. А то к нам уже с теорией музыки идут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/979628

Answer (score 6):

Ну, чтобы хоть как-то разбавить тему, предлагаю на [странице создания нового вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) в блоке справа изменить жирный подзаголовок

> Хотите задать вопрос сообществу Stack Overflow на русском?

на

> Задайте свой вопрос по программированию или системному администрированию на этой странице.

Надо еще что-то сделать с заголовком блока

> Как задавать вопросы

Предлагаю избавиться от него полностью, он не имеет никакой ценности, так как в нижней части блока есть ссылки на инструкции.

Answer (score 4):

Идея в целом здравая и я её поддерживаю. С другой стороны, проблема, имхо, раздута, как и в [вопросе про украинский язык](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8092/176217) в сообщениях, хотя он и был неплохо так поддержан сообществом. Предполагаю, что здесь будет нечто похожее. Ну и конечно, не забывайте, что подобные нетематические вопросы, которые задают люди, незнакомые со Stack Overflow, всё же вносят некоторую частичку юмора на сайт, а это дорогого стоит :)

В конечном же итоге подобные сообщения не будут видны в обычной выдаче поиском по сайту или даже из тех же поисковиков, так что ничего страшного в их наличии на сайте непродолжительное время я не вижу.

Кстати, как оказалось, на английском SO соответствующий текст присутствует в упомянутом блоке при [задании вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask):

> [image: about programming]

Comment: А я и не говорю, что у нас какая-то серьезная проблема. Я говорю, что можно улучшить поисковую выдачу, почему бы этого не сделать? Всё-таки 2 предложения в поисковой выдаче, это как некая аннотация и нужно привести ее в соответствие тематике. Да и место это слишком ценное, чтобы так просто его потратить на ненужные слова :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP допускаю, что владельцы SO настолько уверены в узнаваемости своего бренда, что какие-то дополнительные упоминания программистской тематики излишни. А ещё оказалось, что на ruSO [можно без регистрации](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Os7Wo.png), а на enSO нельзя.

Comment: А управляющие *ruSO* тоже уверены в узнаваемости себя? Среди неайтишников? :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP на ruSO нет выделенного управляющего :)

Answer (score 2):

На 21 мая 2023 года переходя по ссылке [Задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) и не имея аккаунта на ruSO, выводится следующее:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно заметить в первых строках всплывающего окна есть часть "вопрос, связанный с программированием". И в боковой панели так же упоминается про "помочь вам с конкретными проблемами по программированию, алгоритмам, языкам программирования".

Может быть это, конечно, должно быть выделено более жирно, но, как мне кажется, информации о тематике достаточно, чтобы не постить явно офтопичные вопросы.

Comment: [интересно](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6bHq.png) все-таки этот топик изначально про выдачу поисковиков

Comment: @АндрейNOP а есть понимание, откуда (из какой части страницы) поисковик берёт эти строки и будет продолжать брать? в яндексе что-то вообще результат поиска куда-то провалился.

Comment: наверное из заголовка. по крайней мере я там это вижу. Но как поисковик работает — я не знаю, надо читать их гайды. [человеки](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOOAR.png)

Comment: В яндексе — да, в первом случае ссылка на 3ей странице (бесполезно вообще), во втором — опустилась на 6ю позицию с первой. Деградация налицо. Сайт заброшен и не нужен

Comment: @АндрейNOP можно поправить текст про **"вопрос другому человеку"**, чтобы указать там явно про тематику. Но я не сторонник того, чтобы вносить новый смысл в перевод, которого не было в оригинале. Чтобы корректно разрешить этот случай, надо понять всё же какую часть берёт (должен брать) поисковик, и продвигать идею, чтобы этот текст содержал тематику сайта глобально на уровне SE. Т.е. задать вопрос на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). Готов как минимум поддержать его голосом "за", если он будут создан.

Comment: Я точно не буду его создавать, мне это не интересно ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @АндрейNOP не интересно? А текущий вопрос и переписка тут по какой причине появились? :)

Comment: Текущий вопрос я задавал 4,5 года назад :) Так-то в 7 лет я хотел стать космонавтом :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP ну ок, нет так нет, настаивать не буду.